# Another form of Menage Problem : Place 8 more cherries(maroon) removing berries(black) 1 from each row and each column. No of ways?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, combinations

I tried to see it as a matrix where for a position (i,j) , i+j = 8, 9, 16 means you can't change that position.
Any help?

[image]

Comment: This may not be the easiest way to see the answer, but my first instinct is the following: If it was just the one diagonal, do you see how this would relate to the question of finding the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)?  You could approach similarly via inclusion-exclusion.  How many ways can you pick one entry from each row and each column if we ignore that we can't pick red entries for the time being?  How about if the first column choice was one of the red ones?  First two column choices were one of the red ones?  First and third?  etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz can we see it as a round table problem? Just fold the matrix (top to bottom) and you see a perfect pattern right? Also I agree if it was only diagonals , it won't be hard.

Comment: After applying my inclusion-exclusion argument to the $5\times 5$ matrix (the $3\times 3$ and $4\times 4$ cases are trivial) I found there to be thirteen valid arrangements in that case.  Armed with this knowledge, I found http://oeis.org/A000179 which is a rephrasing of your original problem statement.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you elaborate your calculation plz? And give it an answer form for general value? I know u r trying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A^n_k$ be the number of derangements of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that exactly $k$ of the elements map to their right neighbor (viewed cyclically).
Then you're looking for $A^8_0$.

For $0\le k \le n$ we have $$A^n_k = \binom{n}{k} A^{n-k}_{0}$$ This is also true for $k=n$ if we declare that $A^0_0=1$, which doesn't seem unreasonable (after all, the empty map is a derangement of the empty set which doesn't map any element to its right neighbor). On the other hand, we have $A^1_0=A^2_0=0$.

The above recurrence doesn't tell us anything useful for $k=0$, but since $\sum_i A^n_i$ is the number of derangements of $n$ elements, which is known to be $\lfloor n!/e + 1/2\rfloor$, we can write a recurrence for the $A^n_0$s:

$$ A^n_0 = \left\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac12\right\rfloor -
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom nj A^j_0 $$

which one can use directly to compute $A^8_0$ without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks @Henning Makholm and JMoravitz. I finally understood properly. :)